# Cracking Lost Password for encrypted 7z file with most characters known

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, 7zip

I forgot password to 7z archive encrypted with AES 256. I am fairly certain of most characters however. I know password length is either 8 or 12 characters and if it is 12 I know the last 4 characters. I am certain of 1st, 4th, 5th characters. I know the 2nd/6th character 1 of 2 options. 3rd character is 1 of 3 characters. 7th/8th characters can be 13 different possibilities. Is there way to generate password list with known parameters? I have very limited knowledge of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You'll probably want to use Hashcat for this, and they call this a [mask attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack).

You define a mask with the portions you know and a charset for the unknown parts that describes what should be substituted into the unknown parts.

[Here's a tutorial for attacking 7z files](https://infinitelogins.com/2020/04/29/how-to-crack-encrypted-7z-archives/) using Hashcat.